# Does Thunderbird always work as a MAPI Mail Client?

Tags: delphi, mapi, thunderbird

I have an application (which I wrote, in Delphi) with a function to format and send an email, using the underlying OS's MAPI client. I've tested it on four machines, and all works as expected in 3 out of 4 cases. The main difference I've noted is the working machines have Microsoft email clients set as defaults, while the not-working-as-hoped machine has Thunderbird for its default email client. ... Is there something about Thunderbird I don't know? Are there better explanations for what's going on here?

Thanks, as always -- Al C.

Comment: http://kb.mozillazine.org/MAPI_Support

Comment: Not working is not a good description of what's happening... you have better chance to get help if you fully describe the misbehavior you're observing there and what do you expect to see.

Comment: Thanks, jachguate. Good point. ... I expect to see an email client open, formatted with a to: address, a subject line, message text, and an attached file (which I know exists). Instead, no email client opens.

Comment: Thanks, Let_Me_Be. When I get the chance I'll try installing a Microsoft email client, make it the default mail reader, and see what happens ...

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 different implementations of MAPI.  Simple and Extended.  Thunderbird DOES NOT support extendedMapi.  In order to use SimpleMapi all you have to do is set Thunderbird to be the default browser which you already have done.  In this case the problem is either with your program using MAPI in a non standard fashion or that it is trying to use ExtendedMapi.